# ¿Cómo tener una imagen de fondo con un degradado?

Tags: html, css, css3

Tengo un `div` con una imagen de fondo con transparencias de tal manera que, si quiero poner diferentes colores de fondo, ese color se verá a través de las transparencias. Algo como esto:

```css
html,body {
  background:#ddd;
}
div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background: red;
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/scrNdzO.png);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Ahora, si en lugar de ser un sólo color quisiera poner un gradiente (por ejemplo: uno vertical de rojo a azul), no funciona y sólo se ve la imagen o el gradiente, pero no ambos al mismo tiempo:

```css
html,body {
  background:#ddd;
}
div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(red, blue);
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/scrNdzO.png);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

¿Por qué ocurre esto? ¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La propiedad `background-image` soporta múltiples imágenes separadas por coma (,), y como tal la función `linear-gradient()` genera una imagen:

```css
html,body {
  background:#ddd;
}
div {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/scrNdzO.png), linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Referencia background-image: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image

Referencia linear-gradient: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#linear-gradients

Una referencia de documentación más "amigable", con ejemplos: http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/background-image

Answer (score 0):

En vez de utilizar una imagen, puedes utilizar un degradado por medio de CSS3: [Background Degradado con CSS3](https://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/)